# Nonuniqueness of Heegaard surfaces for submanifolds of $S^3$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M^3$ be some compact submanifold of $S^3$ with connected boundary.  I am interested in the failure of the analog of Waldhausen's theorem for $M^3$ - namely, I would like examples of such $M$ together with two Heegaard splitting surfaces in $M$ that are not isotopic.

I thought, I remembered reading about such examples (maybe even with the trefoil complement as $M$) maybe with respect to some "exotic unknotting tunnels", but it could all be a dream.

Comment: See Section 4 of this survey article by Moriah: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608137.pdf